# use of class:any() in PHP, is ANY a reserved method?

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement Simple MVC Framework http://simplemvcframework.com/ and am going through the code line by line in the index.php file (https://github.com/simple-mvc-framework/v2/blob/master/index.php) and I've come across the following 2 lines..

```
//define routes
Router::any('', '\controllers\welcome@index');
Router::any('/subpage', '\controllers\welcome@subpage');
```

I understand `::` is a scope resolution operator, and would think that `Router::any()` would be referencing a static method called `any()` in the `Router` class... however no such method exists...  https://github.com/simple-mvc-framework/v2/blob/master/app/core/router.php.   Though all other static method calls mentioned in the index.php file DO exist.

I thought maybe this was some sort of reserved name of a PHP function, but of course as you could imagine, searching for "PHP Any function" or similar searches in google doesn't come back with too many helpful results.  My other thought is maybe this is just a implementation of static calls that I'm not familiar with?

I know this is a very specific question, but I'm trying to make sure I understand as much as possible with this framework and PHP in general before going too much futher.

Comment: [__callStatic is invoked](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic). When a method doesn't exist, a `__callStatic` is invoked, if specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it works.

It utilizes [__callStatic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) magic method in PHP.

When a static call is made using Class/Object, and if the magic method is defined in the class, and if the called static function doesn't exist then this method is invoked.

If we dig deeper into the code,

```
public static function __callstatic($method, $params){
    $uri = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.$params[0];
    $callback = $params[1];
    array_push(self::$routes, $uri);
    array_push(self::$methods, strtoupper($method));
    array_push(self::$callbacks, $callback);
}
```

The method parameter which is `any` in our case is store as uppercase (`ANY`) with a callback.

When a request is made, dispatch function is called.

```
public static function dispatch(){
    $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];  
    $searches = array_keys(static::$patterns);
    $replaces = array_values(static::$patterns);
    self::$routes = str_replace('//','/',self::$routes);   
    $found_route = false;
    // parse query parameters
    {
        $query = '';
        $q_arr = array();
        if(strpos($uri, '&') > 0) {
            $query = substr($uri, strpos($uri, '&') + 1);
            $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '&'));
            $q_arr = explode('&', $query);
            foreach($q_arr as $q) {
                $qobj = explode('=', $q);
                $q_arr[] = array($qobj[0] => $qobj[1]);
                if(!isset($_GET[$qobj[0]]))
                {
                    $_GET[$qobj[0]] = $qobj[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // check if route is defined without regex
    if (in_array($uri, self::$routes)) {
        $route_pos = array_keys(self::$routes, $uri);
        // foreach route position
        foreach ($route_pos as $route) {
            if (self::$methods[$route] == $method || self::$methods[$route] == 'ANY') {
                $found_route = true;
                //if route is not an object 
                if(!is_object(self::$callbacks[$route])){
                    //call object controller and method
                    self::invokeObject(self::$callbacks[$route]);
                    if (self::$halts) return;
                } else { 
                    //call closure
                    call_user_func(self::$callbacks[$route]);
                    if (self::$halts) return;
                }
            }
        }
        // end foreach
    } else {
        // check if defined with regex
        $pos = 0;
        // foreach routes
        foreach (self::$routes as $route) {
            $route = str_replace('//','/',$route);
            if (strpos($route, ':') !== false) {
                $route = str_replace($searches, $replaces, $route);
            }
            if (preg_match('#^' . $route . '$#', $uri, $matched)) {
                if (self::$methods[$pos] == $method || self::$methods[$pos] == 'ANY') {
                    $found_route = true; 
                    //remove $matched[0] as [1] is the first parameter.
                    array_shift($matched);
                    if(!is_object(self::$callbacks[$pos])){
                        //call object controller and method
                        self::invokeObject(self::$callbacks[$pos],$matched);
                        if (self::$halts) return;
                    } else {
                        //call closure
                        call_user_func_array(self::$callbacks[$pos], $matched);
                        if (self::$halts) return;
                    }
                }
            }
            $pos++;
        }
        // end foreach
    }
    if (self::$fallback) {
        //call the auto dispatch method
        $found_route = self::autoDispatch();
    }
    // run the error callback if the route was not found
    if (!$found_route) {
        if (!self::$error_callback) {
            self::$error_callback = function() {
                header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 404 Not Found");
                echo '404';
            };
        }
        if(!is_object(self::$error_callback)){
            //call object controller and method
            self::invokeObject(self::$error_callback,null,'No routes found.');
            if (self::$halts) return;
        } else {
            call_user_func(self::$error_callback); 
            if (self::$halts) return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

If you look deeply into the dispatch function, you will clearly see that, there are several lines containing:

`if (self::$methods[$route] == $method || self::$methods[$route] == 'ANY')`

This helps routing the request to defined callbacks based on the methods supplied including ANY method.

Comment: ah the __callStatic() makes sense now after looking at the PHP.net documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `any()` is a reserved method, it's that the class is using [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) to call that method. [Look at this code](https://github.com/simple-mvc-framework/v2/blob/master/app/core/router.php#L31) for a second

```
/**
 * Defines a route w/ callback and method
 *
 * @param   string $method
 * @param   array @params
 */
public static function __callstatic($method, $params){
    $uri = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/'.$params[0];
    $callback = $params[1];
    array_push(self::$routes, $uri);
    array_push(self::$methods, strtoupper($method));
    array_push(self::$callbacks, $callback);
}
```

When `any()` is called, PHP first checks for that method being defined directly. Since it's not, it then calls this overloading magic method, which then executes the call.